# Find $\int \frac{1}{x^4+x^2+1} \,\, dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Find $$\int \frac{1}{x^4+x^2+1} \,\, dx$$

---

I tried to find like that:

$\int \frac{1}{x^4+x^2+1} = \int \frac{\frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{2}}{x^2+x+1} \,\, dx + \int \frac{-\frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{2}}{x^2-x+1} \,\, dx = \frac{1}{2} \Big(\int \frac{2x + 1}{x^2+x+1} - \int \frac{x}{x^2+x+1} \Big) - \frac{1}{2} \Big( \int \frac{2x - 1}{x^2-x+1} \,\, dx - \int \frac{x}{x^2-x+1} \,\, dx \Big)$

but then I don't know how to find integrals:
$\, \int \frac{x}{x^2-x+1} \,\, dx \,$ and  $\, \int \frac{x}{x^2+x+1} \,\, dx \,$

Is there another way to integrate this function or way to end my calculations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

simple methods,Note
$$1=\dfrac{1}{2}(x^2+1)+\dfrac{1}{2}(1-x^2)$$
so
$$\int\dfrac{1}{x^4+x^2+1}dx=\frac{1}{2}(I_{1}+I_{2})$$
$$I_{1}=\int\dfrac{x^2+1}{x^4+x^2+1}dx=\int\dfrac{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}{x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}+1}dx=\int\dfrac{d(x-\frac{1}{x})}{(x-1/x)^2+3}$$
and simaler $I_{2}$

Comment: But can we do such trick?
$x^4+x^2+1 \neq x^2(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}+1)$ because of different domains.

Answer (score 0):

The above method is a good way to solve it, however I think you are trying to solve the wrong question because its integral is very complicated.Take a look at this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+1%2F%28x%5E4%2Bx%5E2%2B1%29

Comment: The question is correct. If wolfram doesn't show "simple" integral it doesn't mean that such integral doesn't exist. And in this case it means that output can be simplified (without using imaginary numbers).

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\frac{xdx}{x^2-x+1}=\int\frac{(x-\frac12)dx}{x^2-x+1}+\int\frac{\frac12dx}{(x-\frac12)^2+\frac34}$$.  I'm guessing you know how to solve that.  The other half is very similar.

Comment: But how do you solve $\int \frac{(x-\frac{1}{2}) dx}{x^2-x+1}$ ?

Comment: @VirrageS Would it be easier to rewrite it as $\frac12\int\frac{(2x-1)dx}{x^2-x+1}$?